# Current maven session contains banned plugin repository urls, please double check your pom or settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I tryed to deploy wildfly quickstart 17.0.0 final. But i had some problems with maven.

```
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BannedRepositories failed with message:
Current maven session contains banned repository urls, please double check your pom or settings.xml:
jboss-earlyaccess-repository - http://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all/
jboss-ga-repository - http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all

 Current maven session contains banned plugin repository urls, please double check your pom or settings.xml:
jboss-earlyaccess-plugin-repository - http://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all/
jboss-ga-plugin-repository - http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all
```

I dont know what should i do.

If you need any other information, plz let me know.

Comment: can you show your settings file contents?

Comment: it is default mvn settings.xml

Comment: Remote the mentioned repositories from your pom file...

Comment: but this repositories defined by wildfly quickstart. 
and what exactly should I replace them with

Comment: Define a correct `settings.xml` and redirect all request via a repository manager. That's the issue with repositories defined in pom.xml files...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use SSL replace http with https in your urls.

Comment: To elaborate on this answer, you may need to replace "http" with "https" in your settings.xml, which might be in $USER_HOME/.m2/settings.xml or $MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml.

Answer (score 0):

[ISSUE]
We are facing the BannedRepositories error while building the mvn project.

```
org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BannedRepositories failed with message:
Current maven session contains banned repository urls
```

[ANSWER]

```
We need to check the repository's URL in the settings.xml whether it is HTTP or HTTPS:
So, You should replace HTTP with HTTPS in your URLs as shown below.

------------------
<repository>
          <id>redhat-ga-repository</id>
          <name>Your XYZ repository</name>
          <url>https://maven.repository.xxx.com/ga/</url>
</repository>
---------------------
```