# Can't build WildFly helloworld quickstart with mvn: "banned plugin repository URLs"

Tags: maven, wildfly

I am trying to run the WildFly 23.x helloworld quickstart using `mvn package wildfly:deploy`.  When I try, mvn tells me:

> ```
> Current maven session contains banned repository urls, please double check your pom or settings.xml:
> redhat-ga-repository - http://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/
> jboss-ga-repository - http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all
> ```

The responses to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62299435/current-maven-session-contains-banned-plugin-repository-urls-please-double-chec) suggest checking that poms don't use "http" rather than "https" and checking the settings.xml file. I looked, and I couldn't find any likely culprits:

```
/cygdrive/c/Tools/WildFly/quickstart-23.x

$ grep -r maven.repository.redhat.com/ga *
CONTRIBUTING.adoc:URL: https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/
pom.xml:        <maven.redhat.repository.url>${maven.repository.protocol}://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</maven.redhat.repository.url>
shared-doc/setup-repositories.adoc:        <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
shared-doc/setup-repositories.adoc:        <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>

$ grep -r maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview *
contributor-settings.xml:          <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
contributor-settings.xml:          <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
```

To be extra sure, I replaced "${maven.repository.protocol}" with "https" and replaced the occurrences of "http" with "https" in contributor-setting.xml. My settings.xml is the default one and doesn't seem to have anything interesting in it.  When I reran `mvn package wildfly:deploy`, I still got the same error.

What can be my problem?  Any suggestions for how I can better debug this?

Comment: Are you using the 23.x branch or the 23.0.0.Final tag?

Comment: I am using quickstart-23.x, but wildfly-23.0.0.Final

Comment: I'd suggest using the the [23.0.0.Final tag](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/23.0.0.Final). I don't seem to have an issue building with the tag at all.